# Do we have $f=\mathrm{Id} +c$ if $f'=1$ almost everywhere and $f$ is 1-Lipschitz?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Assume that we have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is $1$-Lipschitz, and so that $f'(x)=1$ almost everywhere.

Can we show that there exist a unique constant $c$ so that $f(x)=x+c$ ?

The main problem of this question is that the constant $c$ that we find depends on the connexe component of the set $R\setminus A=R\setminus \{x \vert f'(x)=1\}$ with $\lambda(A)=1$.
The goal is to find that it is the same constant for any of these components using 1-Lipschitzness of $f$, but I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lipschitz implies absolute continuity. So $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt=f(0)+x$. [See Theorem 7.20 of Rudin's RCA].